# Can not access fastify cookies in middlewares

Tags: nestjs

I try to set `req user`:

```
use(req: any, res: Response, next: () => {}) {
    req.user = this.userService.getUserAuthenticated(req.cookies.t);
    next();
}
```

but `req.cookies is undefined`.

to enable cookie I am using:

```
app.register(require('fastify-cookie'));
```

With `ExecutionContext` in `Interceptor` it is work well, but I need it for gourd , and`canActivate` called before Interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies get parsed in onRequest hook in app [lifecycle of fastify](http://Lifecycle) so if its undefined, then your use take place before, or you have no cookies.

What can you do?

1)Parce cookies by hand from headers.raw.

2)Make your use as hook after onRequest handle of cookies.